# Mysql foreign key constrain remove

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have many foreign keys constrains in many tables where tables are connected using IDs (Foreign keys and primary key) and I want to remove foreign keys constrains because I have divided my database.

I just want to change the foreign key columns to only dummy ints without any constrains.

I am using Workbench with MySQL

Comment: Iterate over INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE in stored procedure and remove all FKs using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a query that generates a set of SQL statements to drop all your foreign keys:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME,
  '` DROP FOREIGN KEY `',  CONSTRAINT_NAME, '`;') AS _sql 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY';
```

Then you would execute the strings output by this query as new queries, one row at a time.